# What are the differences between code deformation, code conversion, code switching and gauge fixing?

Tags: universal-gates, fault-tolerance, lattice-surgery

From my understanding so far: Code switching is essentially just a fault-tolerant mapping between two codes. It's called code conversion if it's gradational, i.e. changes to stabilizer generators are measured in each round of error correction. A non-fault tolerant code conversion is called code deformation. Then you have gauge fixing of which code deformation is an example of (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10037), but then gauge fixing is also an example of code switching according to table 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.05260?

Another example of code switching btw are lattice surgery (which is also example of gauge fixing) and Floquet codes (which cannot be thought of as gauge fixing).

I guess I'm looking for some Venn diagram where I suppose code switching and gauge fixing would be umbrella terms.